# Conditional Github Sync For Java Projects

Tags: java, git, synchronization

I have two projects in Git named Zeus and Odin. Both contain some java packages, files, and libraries. One particular package named Olympos is common to both and contains 'almost' same files. Difference is that files within Olympos for Zeus may have methods that interact with DB, but those in Odin will never  (though it will contain method with same name but only placeholder code). Please look at following example for further clarification:

- **Project:** Zeus;
  **Package:** Olympos;
  **File:** DummyOne.java;
  **Method:**

`public void adapterDB(){
// do something to connect with DB
// do something DB specific- fire queries
}`

- **Project:** Odin;
  **Package:** Olympos;
  **File:** DummyOne.java;
  **Method:**

`public void adapterDB(){
// do nothing and return null;
}`

So the problem- Olympos needs to be in sync at all the times for both the projects, such that when a file change is checked in to Zeus, it automatically syncs  with that of Odin or vice-versa. But it has to happen conditionally:

*- if new method is being checked in to any file that contains DB related operation (in Zeus), only the method header should sync to Odin, without the actual logic
- if new method is being checked in to any file that does NOT contain DB related operation (in either Zeus or Odin), it should completely match in both the packages.*

Obviously, I want to shed off the additional time required to make such changes manually every time and then sync them up separately to these projects since there are like two dozen such changes every week.

Is this something possible using Git? Or there is perhaps more obvious solution outside Git (hope I am not missing elephant in the room).

Comment: git is not the solution to such kind of problems. Are the two projects in different repositories? if so: why? Why don't you have some form Inheritance?

Comment: please format your code as `code`, by using backticks ` for inline code and an indentation of 4 spaces for code blocks (you can also press CTRL+K to format as code)

Comment: @PixelMaster: thanks for the tip. Post updated.

Comment: @FabianH.: yes, both projects exist in separate repositories as they are being directly accessible by separate categories of end users. Also, other packages in both the projects are completely different and may not be allowed to sync. I suspected that Git may not offer the solution. And this is something I am planning to do: Take common code out as a separate project/repository on Git; that is the package for Olympos files. And include its jar in other 2 projects.

Now in both the project I can ask for any of the functionality by passing the type variable's value for relevant function

Comment: ...in continuation to last comment. I am not sure if this is optimal solution though. I am fairly experienced with Java, but unfortunately, I had very limited dealing with Git as SVN.

Comment: Just in case someone else needs solution to this: created a new meta-repository on Git with common files. Included it as library jar to both Zeus and Olympos. Had the meta-repository accept the flags in method definition to indicate the delegation root. And of course, had procedures updated in common repository to handle those flags as well.